# How to make image visible in Blackberry when button is pressed?

Tags: image, blackberry, button

I want to show image when button is pressed on main screen in blackberry, How can I do this?

Simply I have a button, when I do press it, the data is loading from xml, and I want to show that data is loading, how can I do this, I have image(having text on it).
Help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add that image in a vertical field manageer and add the vertical field manager to the screen on the button click. that's it..

Comment: Ya, but can you provide the code of two lines, because I am new to blackberry programming